# Layout paths not working in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Using Sinatra for the web framework and HAML for the pages, I have a layout file at `/views/layout.haml`. I also have javascript and css files in `/public`. Within the layout scripts and css are defined similar to this:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "test.js"}
%link{:rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css", :href => "test.css"}
```

When I have a basic route defined in Sinatra everything works fine:

```
get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

But when the route has multiple parts, such as '/route/1', suddenly the paths to `test.js` and `test.css` no longer work. The haml file loads properly, but the paths in the layout are no longer valid.

After experimenting some, if I change the paths to something like `"//public/test.js"`, instead of just `"test.js"`, it again loads... but only for the route `/route/1`. Unfortunately the first route `/` no longer loads.

How is this typically handled in Sinatra with routes like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure your urls are absolute.

With `:src => "test.js"`, the browser will make a request *relative to the current url*. So for the root, `/`, the request will be for `/test.js` and will work, but when the current page is `/route/1` the request will go to `/route/test.js` and will fail.

The direct fix is to just add `/` to the url, to make the path absolute:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "/test.js"}
```

A more robust solution would be to use the [`url` helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Generating%20URLs):

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => url("/test.js")}
```

This will ensure your app will work even if it is mounted somewhere other than the root of you webserver.